# How to find $\sqrt{3}\pmod 5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was thinking about this but I couldn't solve it. I am trying to find $\sqrt{3}\pmod {10}$. I found that $\sqrt{3}\equiv \pm 1\pmod 2$ but I can't solve $\sqrt{3}\pmod 5$.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find an element of $\Bbb Z_5$ or $\Bbb Z_{10}$ whose square is $3$, there is none (as you can easily check just trying). Just like in $\Bbb R$, not every element of $\Bbb Z_n$ is a square. For more general results, search for the law of quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 0):

The statement $$ \sqrt3 \equiv \pm 1 $$ (mod 2) is false since the difference between $\sqrt3$ and $\pm 1$ is not a multiple of 2.

Comment: .... but I think you are thinking about what ajotatxe says above...

Comment: Can you please explain why its false? Thanks

Comment: @Assaultous2 I think the OP means $\pm 1$ are solutions to the equation $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 2$.