# What is $\sqrt{3}\pmod 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Please explain your answer, thanks.

My attempt: It is $\pm 1$ because $(\pm 1)^2\equiv 1\equiv 3\pmod 2$, so $\pm 1\equiv \sqrt{3}$ by taking square roots.

Comment: I feel like this was sufficiently explained in your [original post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125640/how-to-find-sqrt3-pmod-5).

Comment: This question is not well-posed.  The symbol $\sqrt{3}$ has multiple meanings, as does $\pmod{2}$.

Comment: Good point, Vadim. So, 45220, try the following query in Wolfram Alpha: `(-Sqrt[3])^2`.

Answer (score 1):

$3 \equiv 1 \bmod 2$, and $1^2 =1 \equiv 1 \bmod 2$. So there is a number $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 3 \mod 2$. But it's generally not useful to look at numbers greater than the modulus base.

For a list of bases $b$ where there is an  $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 3 \mod b$, look at [OEIS A057125: Numbers n such that 3 is a square mod n](https://oeis.org/A057125).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to know which congruence classes give $1$ when squared. There are olny two congruence classes you need to check to answer this question.